# What to call all single people?

Tags: vocabulary

What to call a group of people in the society which are all single (meaning not being in relationship). Singles?

Comment: What’s wrong with just _single people_?

Comment: Logically, not native speaker does not know what sounds more natural. If no single word exist (which I honestly thought), it s ok.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's wrong with *single* that it doesn't fit?

Comment: I do understand the question. I just find it funny. Yeah it's *singles* alright. Like, even German and Russian borrowed that, that's how alright it is.

Comment: "Here, single people!  Come here folks!"

Comment: How to call them, what? On this list you would have to ask each what his preferred pronoun was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Singles** is a common word for this:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/single (first noun definition)

*Single people* also works just fine.

I hear the term *singles* a lot when talking about events designed for single people to attend, such as a Friday Singles Mixer, but it works in any context.

Example usage:

> I invited my friend out dancing on Friday. It's just for singles, so
>   hopefully we'll meet some great people!

Note that it's uncommon to call just one person "a single", but when referring to a group of single people, calling them "singles" collectively is correct. When referring to one person, you'd use the adjective *single* ("he is single", "I am single", etc).

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to them as [unattached](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/unattached).

```
adjective: not married or not having a relationship with anyone; single
```

You could call them "unattached people".

In my experience, you would also be understood if you used it as a noun in the same way you would use "singles".  As in...

*I have started a dating service targeted at the unattached.*

Comment: If the meaning the OP wants to express is, as they put it, "not being in relationship", then your "unattached" is a good choice. Some single people are in relationships.

Answer (score -1):

**singleton**

Definition of singleton

1 : a card that is the only one of its suit originally dealt to a player

2a : an individual member or thing distinct from others grouped with it

b : an offspring born singly "singletons are more common than twins"

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/singleton

further source and examples:

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/singleton

1.2 *informal* A person who is not married or in a long-term relationship.

‘At tonight's game there don't seem to be any singletons on the prowl, but there are three couples on the ice.’

‘And 1.95 million single women live in New York City - the Mecca of singletons - alone.’

‘Her job is so much fun, she said, and time-consuming, too, that she has postponed ending her days as a singleton, also fodder for the cynicism and suspicion of others.’

‘This totally non-profit venture will bring singletons together for a night of frivolity.’

Also, https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/singleton

Word forms: plural singletons
countable noun
A singleton is someone who is neither married nor in a long-term relationship.

Bank is a 38-year-old singleton who grew up in Philadelphia.

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer. None of the definitions you provided match what OP is asking for, and based on personal experience, *singleton* isn't the appropriate word for this.

Comment: I have never heard "singleton" used to describe a person who is not in a relationship. The definition does not mention that it is used in this way either. If you can find examples of people (i.e. native speakers) using this word this way, please [edit] your answer.

Comment: Here’s promotional material with someone using it as “a group of ... singletons” in advertising a dating show. https://twitter.com/courtneyact/status/1043760973130141696?s=21